# How can I cycle through 4 LEDs with Timer Off Function (TOF)?

Tags: led, plc, duty-cycle

I have 4 LEDs that need to be turned on and off sequentially and cyclically. This is my code from code warrior:

```
  IF TON2.IN == 1 THEN  
    TON2.PT = 3000;
    TOF(&TON2);
  END_IF  
  IF TON2.Q THEN         
    QB_SET (led_linear_sensor_alarm, 1);
    TON3.IN = 1;
  ELSE
    TON2.IN = 0;
    TOF(&TON2);  
    QB_SET (led_linear_sensor_alarm, 0);

    TON3.PT = 3000;
    TOF(&TON3);
    IF TON3.Q THEN         
      QB_SET (led_oil_level_check_sensor_error, 1);
      TON4.IN = 1;
    ELSE
      TON3.IN = 0;
      TOF(&TON3);  
      QB_SET (led_oil_level_check_sensor_error, 0);
  
      TON4.PT = 3000;
      TOF(&TON4);
      IF TON4.Q THEN         
        QB_SET (led_ptc_motor_temperature_sensor_alarm, 1);
        TON5.IN = 1;
      ELSE
        TON4.IN = 0;
        TOF(&TON4);  
        QB_SET (led_ptc_motor_temperature_sensor_alarm, 0);
      
        TON5.PT = 3000;
        TOF(&TON5);
        IF TON5.Q THEN         
          QB_SET (led_down_hold_pressure_sensor_alarm, 1);
        ELSE
          TON5.IN = 0;
          TOF(&TON5);  
          TON2.IN = 1;
          QB_SET (led_down_hold_pressure_sensor_alarm, 0);
        END_IF           
      END_IF            
    END_IF          
  END_IF
```

The duty cycle of the PLC is 20ms.
But the code is in error because the first LED lights up and that's it. Where am I going wrong with this logic?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks wrong to me at first look. The timers have to be called each scan, the best way is to put them in the bottom of your code.

```
TON(&TON1);
TON(&TON2);
TOF(&TON3);
TOF(&TON4);
TOF(&TON4);
....
```

Then you have to assign the state in .IN value. You can do it also in if..then if you want, the imortant thing is that they are always defined true or false.

```
IF TON2.IN == 1 THEN
```

This is not valid, .IN is input to timer, you have to define it like TON2.IN = true /or/ false, it's not an integer value, rather boolean.

```
  IF TON2.Q THEN         
    QB_SET (led_linear_sensor_alarm, 1);
    TON3.IN = 1;
```

This is simply:

```
  IF TON2.Q THEN         
    QB_SET (led_linear_sensor_alarm, 1);
    .....
```

and

```
TON3.IN := TON2.Q;
```

A bottom of your program should be something like this, then you may use .Q values to set your outputs accordingly.

```
TON1.IN := not TON5.Q;
TON2.IN := TON1.Q;
TON3.IN := TON2.Q;
TON5.IN := TON4.Q;

TON(&TON1);
TON(&TON2);
TON(&TON3);
TON(&TON4);
TON(&TON4);
    ....
```